# rake executes file task when file already exists

Tags: rake

I have a rakefile that executes some (but not all) of it's file tasks even if the files of interest have already been built. The frustrating thing, is that paring down my rake file to a MWE resolves the problem---even though I haven't altered anything wrt the filetask definition, how the files are being selected, the dependencies, or anything else. It seems that simply removing other (file)tasks from the rakefile remedies the problem.

I realize this is a really awful question, but does anyone have ideas about what might be going on here? I'd post sample code, but my MWE works as expected and I don't have any sense for what is causing the problem in the full rake file. All I can think to do is demonstrate that my MWE is literally an excerpt from the full Rakefile, unaltered...

```
➜  solutionmaps cat mwe/Rakefile|sed '/^$/d'|tee a
require 'rake'
require 'rake/clean'
require 'pathname'
HOME = ENV['HOME']
SHARED_ATLAS = "#{HOME}/MRI/Manchester/data/CommonBrains/MNI_EPI_funcRes.nii"
TXT = Rake::FileList["txt/nodestrength/??.mni"]
AFNI_RAW = TXT.pathmap("afni/nodestrength/%n_raw+tlrc.HEAD")
AFNI_RAW.zip(TXT).each do |target,source|
  file target => [source] do
    sh("3dUndump -master #{SHARED_ATLAS} -xyz -datum float -prefix #{target.sub("+tlrc.HEAD","")} #{source}")
  end
  CLOBBER.push(target)
  CLOBBER.push(target.sub(".HEAD",".BRIK"))
  CLOBBER.push(target.sub(".HEAD",".BRIK.gz"))
end

➜  solutionmaps perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/'  Rakefile mwe/Rakefile|sed '/^$/d'|tee b
require 'rake'
require 'rake/clean'
require 'pathname'
HOME = ENV['HOME']
SHARED_ATLAS = "#{HOME}/MRI/Manchester/data/CommonBrains/MNI_EPI_funcRes.nii"
TXT = Rake::FileList["txt/nodestrength/??.mni"]
AFNI_RAW = TXT.pathmap("afni/nodestrength/%n_raw+tlrc.HEAD")
AFNI_RAW.zip(TXT).each do |target,source|
  file target => [source] do
    sh("3dUndump -master #{SHARED_ATLAS} -xyz -datum float -prefix #{target.sub("+tlrc.HEAD","")} #{source}")
  end
  CLOBBER.push(target)
  CLOBBER.push(target.sub(".HEAD",".BRIK"))
  CLOBBER.push(target.sub(".HEAD",".BRIK.gz"))
end

➜  solutionmaps diff a b
➜  solutionmaps
```

And that my mwe works as expected (that is, it does not execute the file task).

```
➜  mwe rake --trace --dry-run afni/nodestrength/02_raw+tlrc.HEAD
** Invoke afni/nodestrength/02_raw+tlrc.HEAD (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke txt/nodestrength/02.mni (first_time, not_needed)
```

But the full rakefile does not.

```
rake --trace --dry-run afni/nodestrength/02_raw+tlrc.HEAD
** Invoke afni/nodestrength/02_raw+tlrc.HEAD (first_time)
** Invoke txt/nodestrength/02.mni (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute (dry run) afni/nodestrength/02_raw+tlrc.HEAD

➜  solutionmaps ls afni/nodestrength/02_raw+tlrc.HEAD
afni/nodestrength/02_raw+tlrc.HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally happened across a possible answer:

> Rake determines that a file task needs to be run if the file doesn’t exist *or if any of the prerequisite file tasks are newer*.

Quoted from: http://madewithenvy.com/ecosystem/articles/2013/rake-file-tasks/

Since my Rakefiles are under heavy development, and my Filetasks are all pretty interrelated, this is probably why my Rakefile always wanted to rebuild everything.

Comment: Sadly your link is dead. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: In the end it was not really a problem. Rake was aware that dependencies may have been changed, and so everything else was being run.